# Getting Error While Building Project Spring Boot . There are test failures

Tags: spring, spring-boot

**My Pom.xml File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
            <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
        </parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>movie-catalog-service</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <name>movie-catalog-service</name>
        <description>Movie Catalog project for Spring Boot</description>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RELEASE</spring-cloud.version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    
        <dependencyManagement>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                    <scope>import</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </dependencyManagement>
    
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    
    </project>
```

**Error**

There are test failures.
Please refer to C:\Users\DELL\Documents\movie-catalog-service\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.

Comment: Fix the tests. I suspect the context fails to load as Spring Cloud Greenwich isn't for Spring Boot 2.6. You need 2021.0 for that. See https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

Comment: yes, I fixed that and saw your comment telling exactly about 2021.0 . Thanks ! @M.Deinum

Comment: For me, I had test failures even though I didn't use any test cases or anything to do with testing! I simply commented out the `contextLoads(){}` method inside `src/test/java`